# need for a start method in java when using threads

Tags: java, multithreading

Why do we need to run the thread through start method and not directly through the run method ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the `run` method contains the code that the new thread should execute.

If you were to call the `run` method, then you'd just execute it on the current thread.

Calling `start` starts the new thread and then executes the `run` method *on the new thread*.

Answer (score 6):

The `run` method just executes the thread's task *in the current thread*. Historically, you would subclass `Thread` and override `run` - although today the preferred mechanism is to pass the `Thread` constructor a `Runnable`. So `run` itself doesn't do any threading - it's `start` which creates a new "actual" thread (as opposed to just a `Thread` object) and makes it execute `run()` when it's started.

Answer (score 1):

The `start()` method tells the JVM that it needs to create a system specific thread. After creating the system resource, it passes the `Runnable` object to it to execute its `run()` method. Calling the `run()` method directly has the "Thread" execute in the same thread as the calling object, not in a separate thread of execution, as intended.

In other words, calling `run()` is just like a normal method call. Whereas, calling `start()` tells the thread to create the necessary system resources and then execute the `run()` method asynchronously.

**EDIT:**

For example,

Pseudo code1:

```
thread one = new thread();
thread two = new thread();
one.run();
two.run();
```

This makes the threads run sequentially,ie, `two.run();` will run only after `one.run();` finishes.

Pseudo code2:

```
thread one = new thread();
thread two = new thread();
one.start();
two.start();
```

In this case both threads start and run simultaneously.

The `start()` method calls the `run()` method asynchronously (doesnt waits for any result, just fires up an action), but when WE call `run()`, it runs synchronously, ie,it waits until `run()` finishes and only then it proceeds to the next line of code.

Answer (score 0):

in java `Thread` is always created in `Stack Memory`.When you create a new Thread it takes new memory in Stack.When you call `start()` method it initialize in new `Stack Memory` and when you call `run()` method it initialize in same `Stack Memory` 
That is why we always call a `Thread` with `start()` method